# CSS Transitions not working?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I cannot seem to get css transitions to work for some reason. I am sure this is a very simple mistake. But I have been hitting my head against the wall for an hour now. I am using mozilla firefox 4.0.1 on windows 7 64bit.

```
<style>
a:link {
 transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
 color: #fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
}

a:hover {
 color: #0072bc;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px #000;
}
</style>
<a href="#">test</a>
```

Comment: Have a look at a tutorial I wrote if you want to find out more: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `-moz-` prefix, as it isn't standardised yet. So:

```
-moz-transition: color 1s ease-in-out;
```

Answer (score 1):

css transition is experimental, but implemented in some engines.
You need to use the specific properties :

```
-moz-transition /* for gecko based like firefox*/
-webkit-transition /* for  chrome safari ... */
-o-transition /* for opera*/
```

Comment: Please not that being experimental also means that the syntax is subject to change.

Comment: I understand that, I just forgot that this was one of the new css properties that still required a browser-specific prefixes.

Comment: And probably -ms-transition for IE10pp2 when it comes out.

Answer (score 0):

this can be also done with jquery / jquery ui so i got working in all browsers here =)
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/ClassTransitions

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the SASS framework for CSS authoring. You will not have to worry about experimental dependencies as the framework takes care of all that for you.